# "cannot be named" when generating declarations

Tags: typescript

I have encountered an odd error in a fairly simple situation.

file `ThingA.ts`

```
export class ThingA {

}
```

file `ThingB.ts`

```
export class ThingB {

}
```

file `Things.ts` (re-export)

```
export {ThingA} from "./ThingA";
export {ThingB} from "./ThingB";
```

file `Test.ts` (uses re-exported classes)

```
import * as things from "./Things";

export class Test {

    public method = (input: things.ThingA)  => {

    };

}
```

This is what I use to compile: (typescript version 1.8.10)

```
tsc Test.ts --declaration --outDir compiled
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Test.ts(5,5): error TS4029: Public property 'method' of exported class has or is using name 'ThingA' from external module ".../ThingA" but cannot be named.
```

The issue is with generating declaration file for `Test.ts`. All files are compiled to .js and each file has a generated .d.ts, except for `Test.ts` due to the errors above. If `--declaration` is removed from the compile command, there are no errors.

Some observations:

1) the error doesn't appear for every reference of `things.ThingA`. If it is referenced as a method parameter as in the provided example, or as a return value, the error appears. If it is referenced in a method body, then there are no errors. I realize this is because references in a method body will not even be mentioned in the generated .d.ts but I still don't understand why tsc cannot infer the actual class type from a `things.ThingA` reference.

2) if I change the import statement in `Test.ts` to this:

```
import {ThingA,ThingB} from "./Things";
```

(instead of `import * as things`) and further use `ThingA` directly, there are no errors. This is not really a solution though, as it kind of defeats the purpose or re-exporting.

3) if I just remove `export` from `export class Test {` in `Test.ts`, there are no errors, but `Test.d.ts` file is empty. Even if it wasn't, this would also not be a solution because this is a simplified case of the actual code in which the equivalent of `Test.ts` is used (imported) in a different file so class `Test` has to be exported.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Just ran into this same issue today, trying to convert a project from internal TS modules (namespaces) to external modules, while keeping .d.ts files. This put a damper on the whole thing since I really need to be able to generate .d.ts files so I can include this in another TS project. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspected this is a bug and so posted an issue on typescript github and indeed it is.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8612